# Handling entities in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-proptypes

I am very new to react, redux, prop-types and so on. I am coming from the Angular2 world with TypeScript support. There I had my own entity classes which I imported in the components where I need them. Now in react I only have prop-types which I define for each component.

All fine and good but how would you solve this data structure with prop-types:

```
{
    "order": {
        "date": "2018-03-20",
        "customer": {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Brown"
        },
        "product": {
            "category": "book",
            "name": "XYZ"
        },
        "price": 99
    }
}
```

In Angular2 I would have made three entities, but how I will handle this in react with prop-types? Sure I can define the correct prop-types for this data structure in each component where I got an order entity passed via props but this looks like a huge code redundancy for me.

**My question now**: Is there any best practice solution for this problem? Maybe a central prop-types schema like this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-entity?
(I don't want to use this module because it seems that it is not under development anymore)

Comment: You can use typescript with react

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? Making sure other developers don't pass a prop with the wrong structure?

Comment: @JoeWarner I don't want do use TypeScript with react because of some extern modules like redux-forms don't work quite well with it.

Comment: what about flow?

Comment: @azium No I just don't want repeat myself in defining the prop-types for example a customer entity. I want to declare the data structure for each entity only once and not in every component where I got a customer entity passed via props.

Comment: @JoeWarner I think I will take a look at flow. I just thought I could solve this problem without an external library.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use types in `React` that are richer than what `PropTypes` can provide you, you have two options:

- Use [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/). This does not come out of the box, so you have to change your build. There are a bunch of [bootstrapper projects](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter) that can make your life easier.
- Use [Flow](https://flow.org/). The standard bootstrappers such as [CRA](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) come with support for it out of the box.

Which one to use is a matter of preference at the end. Both have their advantages. [Here](https://github.com/niieani/typescript-vs-flowtype) you have a pretty good comparison of what both can do.

Comment: I think I take a look at flow. I just thought I could achieve a solution for my problem using `PropTypes` only.